# How to quit from iPhone application on button action?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I want my Application to exit when I tap on the quit button. I used `exit(0)`, but Apple has rejected my Application. What are the alternate solutions for this?

Comment: Despite that duplicate referencing iOS 4.0, it is still perfectly valid today.

Answer (score 2):

`From apple doc...`

> ## [**Don’t Quit Programmatically**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html)
>
> ---
>
> Never quit an iOS app programmatically because people tend to interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent your app from functioning as intended, you need to tell your users about the situation and explain what they can do about it. Depending on how severe the app malfunction is, you have two choices.
>
> **Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a correction**. A screen provides feedback that reassures users that there’s nothing wrong with your app. It puts users in control, letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and continue using your app or press the Home button and open a different app
>
> **If only some of your app's features are unavailable, display either a screen or an alert when people use the feature**. Display the alert only when people try to access the feature that isn’t functioning.
>   `

[How do I programmatically quit my iOS application?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html)